# Handlebars access to nested properties

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use handlebars to print a list I'm getting from a json. The data structure is complex (to me) so I can't seem to get to the nested property I need.

The data looks like this:

```js
var data = [{
    "response": {
        "status": "ok",
        "indexes": {
            "child": [
                {
                    "isDir": false,
                    "contentType": "video/avi",
                    "suffix": "avi",
                },
                {
                    "isDir": false,
                    "contentType": "video/avi",
                    "suffix": "avi",
                }
            ],
            "index": [
                {
                    "name": "A",
                    "dataIneed": [
                        {
                            "id": 291,
                            "name": "Example1"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 292,
                            "name": "Example2"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 293,
                            "name": "Example3"
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "lastModified": 1385842880050
        },
        "xmlns": "http://example.org/restapi",
        "version": "123"
    }
}]
```

In a table I want to print:

- Example1
- Example2
- Example3

my html / handlebars looks like this:

```
<table class="table">
    {{#each }}
        <tr><td>
            {{response.indexes.index.0.dataIneed.0.name}}
        </td></tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

And is able to print:

- Example1

How do I loop get the result I want?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify where to loop

```
<table class="table">
  {{#each esponse.indexes.index.0.dataIneed}}
    <tr><td>
      {{this.name}}
    </td></tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, i think i found a way to do what i wanted.

Comment: @esdrayker and what was that way you found?